# Vue2: CSS not working on Iphone Devices with pending IOS Update

Tags: css, iphone, vue.js, mobile, media-queries

I've deployed my website on Ionos with the deploy now feature. The problem is, the website gets broken on some IPhone devices.
Some of my friends tested the website on there devices and for example on an IPhone 11 with current ios update everything is working fine. But if its pending, then the css gets broken. The problems is with chrome and safari and probably other browsers. We tried to use only plain css. So no animations or transform
We are using Vue2 with Bootstrap, Fontawesome and vue-router.

```
"dependencies": {
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.4.2",      
"@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.4.2",      
"@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.4.2",      
"@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.4.2",      
"@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^2.0.10",      
"bootstrap-vue": "^2.23.1",      
"core-js": "^3.8.3",      
"vue": "^2.6.14",      
"vue-router": "^3.6.5"    
},
```

I have been debugging and researching all day and am now at a dead end.

Has anyone experienced anything similar and have any ideas?
I don't want to post all the code right now because I don't have a place to go. If you have an idea what it could be, I'll be happy to post the code

Example of css of the main view

```
import NavigationbarComp from "@/components/NavigationbarComp.vue";
import FourImagesComp from "@/components/FourImagesComp.vue";
import ZeitenComp from "@/components/ZeitenComp.vue";
import SaunaComp from "@/components/SaunaComp.vue";
import LocationComp from "@/components/LocationComp.vue";
import SlideShowComp from "@/components/SlidingShowComp.vue";
import PartnerComp from "@/components/PartnerComp.vue";
import BenefitsComp from "@/components/BenefitsComp.vue";
import FooterComp from "@/components/FooterComp.vue";
export default {
  components: {
    PartnerComp,
    SlideShowComp,
    LocationComp,
    SaunaComp,
    ZeitenComp,
    NavigationbarComp,
    FourImagesComp,
    BenefitsComp,
    FooterComp,
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <main class="homeview">
    <NavigationbarComp />
    <body>
    <section class="container-fluid homeview-div" id="home">
      <div class="homeView-content">
        <img class="background" src="../assets/images/stocks/background.jpg" alt="background_image"/>
        <img class="logo" src="../assets/images/logo/caprice_logo.png" alt="caprice_logo">
        <h1 class="homeView-title">NO PAIN NO GAIN</h1>+
      </div>
    </section>
    <FourImagesComp />
    <ZeitenComp />
    <SlideShowComp/>
    <benefits-comp/>
    <sauna-comp/>
    <location-comp/>
    <PartnerComp/>
    </body>
    <FooterComp/>

  </main>
</template>

<style scoped>

body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #0D0E14;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1300px)
{
  .homeview-div {
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    .homeView-content {
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      position: relative;


      .background{
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        position: absolute;
        object-position: center;
        object-fit: cover;

      }

      .homeView-title {
        margin: auto;
        color: white;
        font-family: "Alfa Slab One", serif;
        font-size: 100px;
        text-align: center;
        letter-spacing: 0.1em;
        z-index: 2;
        position: absolute;
      }

      .logo {
        max-height: 80%;
        max-width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        margin: auto;

      }
    }
  }
}

  @media only screen and (max-width: 1300px)
{
    .homeview-div {
      display: block;
      padding: 0;
      width: 100%;

      .homeView-content {
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        position: relative;


        .background{
          height: 100vh;
          width: 100%;
          margin: 0;
          position: absolute;
          object-position: center;
          object-fit: cover;

        }

        .homeView-title {
          margin: auto;
          color: white;
          font-family: "Alfa Slab One", serif;
          font-size: 80px;
          text-align: center;
          letter-spacing: 0.1em;
          z-index: 2;
        }

        .logo {
          max-height: 80vh;
          max-width: 100%;
          position: absolute;
          margin: auto;

        }
      }
    }
  }

  @media only screen and (max-width: 900px)
{
    .homeview-div {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 0;
      .homeView-content {
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        position: relative;


        .background{
          height: 100vh;
          width: 100%;
          margin: 0;
          position: absolute;
          object-position: center;
          object-fit: cover;

        }

        .homeView-title {
          margin: auto;
          color: white;
          font-family: "Alfa Slab One", serif;
          font-size: 50px;
          text-align: center;
          letter-spacing: 0.1em;
          z-index: 2;
        }

        .logo {
          max-height: 80vh;
          max-width: 100%;
          position: absolute;
          margin: auto;

        }
      }
    }
}

  @media only screen and (max-width: 600px)
{
    .homeview-div {
      display: block;
      padding: 0;
      width: 100%;
      .homeView-content {
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        position: relative;


        .background{
          height: 100vh;
          width: 100%;
          margin: 0;
          position: absolute;
          object-position: center;
          object-fit: cover;

        }

        .homeView-title {
          margin: auto;
          color: white;
          font-family: "Alfa Slab One", serif;
          font-size: 50px;
          text-align: center;
          letter-spacing: 0.1em;
          z-index: 2;
        }

        .logo {
          max-height: 80vh;
          max-width: 100%;
          position: absolute;
          margin: auto;

        }
      }
    }
  }

</style>
```

Website broken
[image]
Website working
[image]

If you want to test it, you can go on the website [caprice-fitness.de](https://caprice-fitness.de)
Unfortunately I dont have an Iphone device to test and debugg that problem

I thought it could be the media queries, because of the retina display and tried to fix that, but didn't work. Later I've learned that it seems to be a problem with the ios version.

Comment: On what versions of iOS is it working and on what versions is it not working. Without seeing the relevant CSS I don’t think we can help properly.

Comment: For example: with an Iphone 13 with IOS-Version 16.1.1 it isn't working. But with 16.6 it is working. 
Ok, I will add the code of the main file and some images how should look like and what it looks like broken
Maybe that could help

Comment: You could try boiling the code right down,  just to try the object-fit and position of the background image. And try it as a background-image also.

Comment: ok, I will try it when I'm back from my vacation in 2 months. It was a last minute bug. But thanks for the idea